# Change font-family for my website without tff

Tags: html, font-face

Having a difficult time trying to get the proper .ttf file from the font family and set-up into my website.

https://freefontsdownload.net/free-futura_bk_bt-font-73014.htm

```
body {
  font-family: Algerian ;
}
```

can i know what is the font-family for the link i provided ? ( does not wanted to download and save it into my server )

Comment: It's 'Futura Bk BT'. The font is not available without additional font files. You can check which type of fonts is available without importing font files and able to be rendered by your browser at here [W3C Font Families](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/fonts.en.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly import fonts that can be found on [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/)
with  tags without needed to download and serves the font files locally. However, there are also fonts that are not available on Google Fonts. For those fonts, you can only download and serve it locally on server there's no way to escape. Or you may try to search and see is there anyone who have the font files on their server and then directly use theirs', but I can say most probably you wont be able to use as you will be blocked by CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing).

It's actually quite simple to setup fonts. After you downloaded the font files, normally there will be font files (eot, ttf, svg, woff...) and a CSS file, just put the font files somewhere on your server (prefer on root folder named "fonts"). Then open the CSS and edit the source to the directory that you store your font files ealier. `url("../fonts/your-font.ttf")`

Answer (score 0):

simply go onsite of google font choose font then copy meta tag then use font family.